# Генерация криптокошельков из Brainwallet

Tags: python, php, perl, blockchain

Есть 70 блокчейнов, необходимо сгенерировать по ним адреса и закрытые ключи по одному только Brainwallet.

На эту тему есть какая-либо информация? Или нужно колупать отдельно каждый опенсорс проект?

Возможно библиотеки какие.

Аналогично Private Key > адрес

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Всё зависит от их технологической базы - вряд ли это 70 оригинальных разработок, скорее всего это форки Ethereum, Bitcoin и так далее...

Comment: Скорее всего там HD кошельки, поэтому шагов преобразования будет намного больше